# How add null widget in column in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a specific widget that I want to add in column in specific condition.

If condition will grant than widget will add in column.

else I don't want to add any widget

```
Column(
  children:<>[
   MyWidget(str,db)
  ]
)



MyWidget(String s, double d) {
    print(s);
    switch(s){
      case 'M':
        return Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          height: d,
        );
      case 'T':
        return null;
    }
  }
```

Here I got error

```
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'
```

I understand this problem ,However I don't want to add any kind of widget to the column.

Please don't suggest

```
SizeBox.shrink
empty widget
Container()
```

Once again **I don't want to add any kind of widget to the column.** **if condition will not satisfied** , how to resolve this ?

Comment: why not if(s=='M'){ // return widget} , so it will only run if the condition is met? also the return type should be Widget? with null safety

Comment: I tried only if condition, but it throws exception when s equals to T

Comment: because your return type was widget it does not accept null as null is not a type of widget so you have to change the return type to Widget? to tell flutter that the value will either be a widget or null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```dart
Column(
  children:<>[
  if(str=='M') 
      Container(
         color: Colors.red,
         height: db,
      ),
  ]
),
```

Comment: what about when condition will not satisfied....it throws null exception

Comment: No it won't throw null exception. Try it out. Accept and vote answer If it works.

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: That's Great.... !

Answer (score 0):

As per your code try to declare the values of String and double variables like below or main thing null is not type of Widget so declare return type is Widget only

your function:

```
myWidget(String s, double d) {
    print(s);
    switch (s) {
      case 'M':
        return Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          height: d,
        );
      case 'T':
        return Container();
    }
  }
```

Your Widget:

```
Column(
  children:[
   myWidget('M', 12.0),
  ]
)
```

Refer my same answer [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68649053/13997210)

Result Screen-> [image]